# How to release with Maven in continuous integration?

Tags: java, maven, continuous-deployment

A philosophic question with Maven in continuous integration.

In Maven we had the famous command `mvn release:release` to release the project. This changes the release in the `pom.xml`.

Now, we use continuous integration/deployment, is there always any utility to release the project with the Maven way?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your question cause you already mentioned maven-release-plugin ? so Where is the problem?

Comment: I think your question would be best suited for Software Engineering: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Your question could be reworded better but see this maven release plugin. Releasing a project is made in two steps: prepare and perform.

[Maven Release Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/)